# rapidxml weird parsing for one specific node

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, rapidxml, tmx

I've been looking for hours a solution to my (simple ?) problem but I cannot find anyone who encountered this. I'm using latest version of rapidxml(1.13).
I'm currently trying to create a tile-based engine and I need to read tmx file.
I'm been using rapidxml for a while and so far everything was great. It was able to  read every node perfectly and with an expected behavior. But I came across one node it has a problem with.
This is my tmx file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.5" tiledversion="1.6.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="100" height="100" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" infinite="0" nextlayerid="12" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="../../../Tile_engine/Tile_engine/sprite/[Base]BaseChip_pipo.tsx"/>
 <tileset firstgid="1065" source="../../../Tile_engine/Tile_engine/sprite/collision.tsx"/>
 <layer id="4" name="background" width="100" height="100">
  <properties>
   <property name="bg" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="csv">
//I've removed the data for clearer view
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="6" name="object" width="100" height="100">
  <properties>
   <property name="isSolid" type="bool" value="true"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="csv">
//I've removed the data for clearer view
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="9" name="front" width="100" height="100">
  <properties>
   <property name="isSolid" type="bool" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="csv">
//I've removed the data for clearer view
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="11" name="collision" width="100" height="100">
  <data encoding="csv">
//I've removed the data for clearer view
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

In order to debug, I'm using a basic read with rapidxml :

```
 xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<> * root_node;
    // Read the xml file into a vector
    ifstream theFile ("sprites/map_wtf.tmx");
    vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    buffer.push_back('\0');
    // Parse the buffer using the xml file parsing library into doc
    doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);
    // Find our root node
    root_node = doc.first_node("map");
```

When I try to read (and count) the **layer** node for example :

```
int count_node(0);
    for(xml_node<> * child = root_node->first_node("layer"); child != nullptr; child = child->next_sibling())
        count_node++;
    cout    <<  count_node;
```

The output is correct and gives me 4.
But when I try to read the **tileset** node, the output gives me 6.

So I've assumed the behavior is link to the /> at the end of the tileset node (`<tileset firstgid="1" source="../../../Tile_engine/Tile_engine/sprite/[Base]BaseChip_pipo.tsx"/>`).

Since the nested **property** node has the same pattern (`<property name="bg" type="bool" value="false"/>`), I've tried this code :

```
int count_node(0);
    for(xml_node<> * child = root_node->first_node("layer")->first_node("properties")->first_node("property"); child != nullptr; child = child->next_sibling())
        count_node++;
    cout    <<  count_node;
```

who gives me the correct output aka : 1.

I've tried different parsing options for the line `doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0])` but nothing works. I've also read the content of the buffer during theses tests and it was correct.
I must have the wrong way to read the file but I cannot understand why this script reads **layer** node and **property** node fine, but not the **tileset** ones.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: Looks about right... on the root level, starting with the first `tileset` node and counting all nodes on the same level that follow after it, I see a total of 6 nodes. For a `label`, I see 4 nodes, since the 2 `tileset` nodes come before label. Since each `layer/properties/property` is a single nested node, the answer is 1. You can try if I'm right by adding another node with a different name as last child of `map` and see if your answers change from 6 to 7 for tileset, from 4 to 5 for label and not at all for nested property.

Comment: @grek40 I feel so dumb .. I thought next_sibling() looks for analogs nodes (with the same name)! Thanks you so much for your quick answer !!

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on a misunderstanding about the result of

```
xml_node<> * child = root_node->first_node("layer");
child = child->next_sibling();
```

The `child = child->next_sibling()` returns the next node on the same level irregardless of the node name or any other constraint that was applied during the `root_node->first_node("layer")` selection.

However, the `next_sibling` signature is basically the same as the `first_node` signature, so it can be used to apply criteria to the next sibling node to be found.

So the (untested) approach would be like

```
int count_node(0);
for(xml_node<> * child = root_node->first_node("tileset"); child != nullptr; child = child->next_sibling("tileset"))
    count_node++;
cout << count_node;
```